# Can I check with a T-sql statement if an name is a table/view/storedProcedure/trigger....;

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can I check with a T-sql statement if an name is a table/view/storedProcedure/trigger....;

I want to return 1 row with 2 columns Name, Type.

I know in information_schema.tables, I can find if a `Table_Name` is a Table or A view. but not if it is a sp or a trigger or a function.

Comment: Are you using Sybase or MS SQL Server?

Comment: `type` in `sys.objects`. [the doc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql)

Comment: I use MS SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sys.all_objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-all-objects-transact-sql) table Store every properties you need:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   sys.all_objects so
WHERE  so.name = 'Something'
```

`type_desc` will give you the description of the object type and `type` is the object type Object type

- AGGREGATE_FUNCTION
- CHECK_CONSTRAINT
- DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT
- FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT
- SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION
- CLR_SCALAR_FUNCTION
- CLR_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION
- SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION
- INTERNAL_TABLE
- SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE
- CLR_STORED_PROCEDURE
- PLAN_GUIDE
- PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT
- RULE
- REPLICATION_FILTER_PROCEDURE
- SYSTEM_TABLE
- SYNONYM
- SERVICE_QUEUE
- CLR_TRIGGER
- SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION
- SQL_TRIGGER
- TABLE_TYPE
- USER_TABLE
- UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT
- VIEW
- EXTENDED_STORED_PROCEDURE

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can use object_id and pass different parameters

for example ,if `object_id('tablename','u')` checks for users table existence

In `information_schema.tables` you can find only tables, you have to look for other views  like information_schema.views and routines for stored procs

below are total types

```
AF = Aggregate function (CLR)

C = CHECK constraint

D = DEFAULT (constraint or stand-alone)

F = FOREIGN KEY constraint

FN = SQL scalar function

FS = Assembly (CLR) scalar-function

FT = Assembly (CLR) table-valued function

IF = SQL inline table-valued function

IT = Internal table

P = SQL Stored Procedure

PC = Assembly (CLR) stored-procedure

PG = Plan guide

PK = PRIMARY KEY constraint

R = Rule (old-style, stand-alone)

RF = Replication-filter-procedure

S = System base table

SN = Synonym

SO = Sequence object



Applies to: SQL Server 2012 through SQL Server 2016.



SQ = Service queue

TA = Assembly (CLR) DML trigger

TF = SQL table-valued-function

TR = SQL DML trigger

TT = Table type

U = Table (user-defined)

UQ = UNIQUE constraint

V = View

X = Extended stored procedure
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select from DatabaseName.Sys.Objects where Name is like your name for search. Or you can user this syntax:

```
OBJECT_NAME ( object_id [, database_id ] )
```

Or in yourdatabasename.sys.all_objects. For example

```
SELECT *
FROM yourdatabasename.sys.all_objects
WHERE upper(name) like upper('my prefix%')
```

Comment: The name does not tell you what the object is. Prefixing objects is generally not a good idea. Just imagine what you should do if you have to create a view out of an existing table because of redesign. Will you rewrite all the queries from TBL_ prefix to VW_ prefix?